# iOS App store itunes country specific link

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a app on the appstore and I want to direct user to the itunes page that is specific to their country if they open it from a desktop web browser (not from the phone).

For example the link to the app is https://itunes.apple.com/app/xxx/idxxxxxxx.

So let say I want to show the page to Thailand users. 
I assume it will be https://itunes.apple.com/th/app/xxx/idxxxxxx.

However,the page still displays everything in English. How do I make it display it in Thai?
I have already activated the Thai language and provided the translation in itunes connect. It shows up correctly on the phone but not on a desktop web browser.

Please advice.